# Face Detect com Javascript

Tags: javascript, ionic, cordova-plugin

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo usando Ionic1, preciso de desenvolver uma função que irá identificar uma pessoa pela foto.

Alguém conhece algum plugin que me ajudaria com isso?

Cheguei a encontrar este serviço:

https://www.luxand.com/facesdk/?gclid=CjwKCAiA_ojVBRAlEiwAOLRxI-fiIBNBlC_pw8xClvkpxWym3Mwe2AfImTEnTtw9i-Q-AQWryAWWmhoCnZYQAvD_BwE

Mas eu quero mesmo um plugin, ou alguma forma que eu não precise de contratar uma `API`

Obrigado!

Comment: Pior que pra você fazer isso "na mão", você teria que treinar uma IA para reconhecer rostos, e depois as diferenças entre dois rostos. Isso demanda bastante processamento e tempo. Por isso a maioria das apis sobre isso são pagas.

Comment: @WeslleyRocha você teria alguma sugestão de API?

Comment: Eu não sei qual é boa, pois nunca usei uma, mas tem a cloud vision api do google, que voce pode user de graça por um tempo

Comment: achei um artigo que voce pode ver, 
https://medium.com/@muehler.v/node-js-face-recognition-js-simple-and-robust-face-recognition-using-deep-learning-ea5ba8e852

Comment: @WeslleyRocha obrigado!

Comment: OpencvJs é uma boa.

Comment: @edsonalves não sabia que existe, obrigado pela dica.